# Dynamic Programming - efficient iteration over a set of stacks

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Let's say I have a set of `n` stacks. Each stack `si` has `mi` elements (arbitrary integers). And now I want to play a little game: at any point during the game I can pop any subset of the stacks provided their top elements are equal. Depending on the number of stacks popped `p`, I then get a certain amount of points: 0 if `p==1`, otherwise 2<sup>p-2</sup>.

If I wanted to calculate the maximum amount of points I can get with an optimal strategy, how would I best iterate over these stacks?

The best I could think of is creating a `m1 x ... x mn` table T, where `T(i1,...,in)` = maximum achievable points when stack `k` has `ik` elements left (i.e. stack `1` has `i1` elements left, ... , stack `n` has `in` elements left).
 To calculate `T(i1,...,in)`, we would first determine the set `S` of stacks that still have at least one element on them; let its size be `d`.

If `d < 2` then `T(i1,...,in)` can be calculated right here and there. Otherwise, we count `c = 1 to 2^d` and for each `c`, we use its binary representation to determine a "current selection" `cs` from `S`, check the validity criterion for the top-elements of the stacks contained in `cs` and if satisfied, look at `T(j1,...,jn)` to calculate a "candidate solution", where

`jk = k in cs ? ik - 1 : ik`

If `T(j1,...,jn)` has not been calculated yet, we calculate it first, of course. `T(i1,...,in)` is then set to the maximum of these "candidate solutions".

Alternatively, we could start at `T(0,...,0)` and just fill the whole thing up.

Either way, this is too slow. However, I fail to come up with something smarter. Any help/hints you could share with me?

Comment: `provided their top elements satisfy a certain criterion` That is...?

Comment: @deviantfan: They all need to be equal, in my case.

Comment: How is the score calculated? What values can elements have? What does `T(i1,...,in)` represent?

Comment: @JanneKarila  values: arbitrary integers, score: 0 if only one element removed, 2^(nof_elements_removed - 2) otherwise, ``T(i1,...,in)`` = maximum achievable points when stack ``k`` has ``ik`` elements left (i.e. stack ``1`` has ``i1`` elements left, ... , stack ``n`` has ``in`` elements left).